# NSThread in background IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsthread

I have a timer that calls a new thread, this thread calls a function that is working on pararelo, but when the app is in the background after a while it freezes. My code follows

in DidLoad:

```
timerMusica = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(15) target:self selector:@selector(treadAtualizaMusica) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

...
function that calls new thread:

```
-(void)treadAtualizaMusica{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(atualizaMusica:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

action that is executed:

```
- (void)atualizaMusica:(NSTimer *)aNotification{
    NSURL *dataUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxx.com.br/musica.php"];
    NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:dataUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"buscando string");

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (fileString == NULL) {
            autoScrollLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxxx"];
            autoScrollLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            autoScrollLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12 ];

        }
        else{
            autoScrollLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileString];
            autoScrollLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            autoScrollLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12 ];
        } 

    }
   else{
        if (fileString == NULL) {
            scrollMusica.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxxx"];
            scrollMusica.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            scrollMusica.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12 ];

        }
        else{
            scrollMusica.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileString];
            scrollMusica.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            scrollMusica.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12 ];
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know if it is the correct way to open a new thread, but that's what I found searching.

I need this separate thread because my function looks for a string in a server, and the connection of the User is slow, the app is locked while this downloading. This above code solved this problem but created another me, as I mentioned above when the app is in the background after a while it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no background thread running in iOS when you are switching task.
You need to ask for permission to continue to run a little more.
Using

> UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Comment: right about now I am researching.

but you have any examples of how to implement? Until now I could not understand the method ...


Thank you!

Comment: instead of detaching a thread you run your code in this method block

Comment: @JoãoLuiz call that method on `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` supplying a block of continuation code. If it's what's causing the confusion, iOS explicitly allows you only to ask for a small amount of extra time to do some sort of critical additional task. You're not permitted to continue running indefinitely for an arbitrary purpose.